# I have problem about converting char to int when adding large numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm, type-conversion, stack

I was doing a problem that requires me to make **addition** of large numbers [here](https://codeup.kr/problem.php?id=3021&rid=0) but I can't solve it:

> | Problem Description |
> | --- |
> | Int is 32-bit, long long is 64 bit, and cannot store larger numbers than this. Write a program to add two large numbers. |
>
> | Input | Output |
> | --- | --- |
> | Enter large numbers a and b in the first and second lines. (a, b are integers up to 100 digits) | Output the result of large number addition. |
>
> | Input Example | Output Example |
> | --- | --- |
> | 12345678910111213 2839287 | 12345678912950500 |

This is what I have so far:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
stack<int> c,d;//stack for adding large numbers
int main(){
    char a[100]={'0'};
    char b[100]={'0'};//input variables
    int i=0,j=0,m;
    scanf("%s %s", a, b);
    while (a[i] != '\0') {
        i++;
    }

    i--;
    while (b[j] != '\0') {
        j++;
    }
    j--;
    if (i>j) {
        m=i;
    } else {
        m=j;
    }
    for (int o=0;o<=m;o++) {
         c.push((int)a[o] - '0');//main problem is converting char to int.
    }

    for (int o=0;o<=m;o++) {
         d.push((int)b[o] - '0');
    }

    int carry=0;//carry variable

    for (int o=0;o<=m;o++) {        
        if (c.top()+d.top()+carry>=10) {
            printf("%d", c.top() + d.top() + carry - 10);
            carry=1;
        } else {
            printf("%d", c.top() + d.top() + carry);
            carry=0;
        }
        c.pop();
        d.pop();
    }
    if (carry > 0) {
        printf("%d", carry);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried using stack that I learned 6 days ago, but it didn't work at`c.push((int)a[o] - '0');`.

I am excepting to solved this problem. I tried `-'0'`, or I was confused. I did as many things as possible.

Comment: What is the expected and actual behaviour? Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger to see what does the `push` does?

Comment: Your code to convert a char to an int looks fine to me. Why do you think that is the problem?

Comment: I think the real problem is that your code doesn't not deal correctly with two numbers that have a different number of digits. You end up trying to convert a `'\0'` character at the end of the shorter number to a digit. That does not work.

Comment: Well...when i used printf to check wrong number,i saw minus number.i tried to solve the problom,no worked.the code workbooks problem is"Addition of large numbers"

Comment: Sorry to wrong codes.thats not going easy.

Comment: @해공부 Yes, you see a negative number because you are trying to convert the null terminator at the end of a string to a digit. Your conversion code is fine, but it will not work on characters which are not decimal digits.

Comment: Thanks i will check my codes again.have a good evening

Comment: Unrelated: Why `char a[100] = { '0' };`? Why are you using arrays instead of `std::string`? Why are you using `scanf`?

Comment: Casting is unnecessary, just `a[o] - '0'` should do the right thing.

Comment: Why do you write a `while` loop to calculate the length of the string? Use `std::strlen()`.

Comment: Thanks sir.i will search about that.have a good day.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo  thanks.i will search to that too.n have a good day.

Comment: Looks like your teaching material is out of date. Some good resources to learn C++ from are [learncpp.com](https://www.learncpp.com/) for your initial steps (it is very decent for an online tutorial). 
Then use [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) to lookup everything C++ has to offer. 
And finally use the [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) to keep up to date with how C++ evolves and how it is supposed to be used.

Comment: Also, next time you ask a question here, please do not say "not working".  In programming, there is no such thing as "not working". There is always an error message, or an expected vs. observed behavior.  State precisely what happened.

Comment: Thank for your lession.i will not ask question that include not working.have a good day,sir.

Comment: [What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/whats-the-problem-with-using-namespace-std)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed the code like so:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string a, b;
    stack<int> c, d;
    vector<int> result;  // Store the result in a vector.

    cin >> a >> b;

    for (int o = 0; o < a.length(); o++) {
        c.push(a[o] - '0');
    }
    for (int o = 0; o < b.length(); o++) {
        d.push(b[o] - '0');
    }

    int m = max(a.length(), b.length());
    int carry = 0;

    for (int o = 0; o < m; o++) {
        int digitSum = carry;
        if (o < a.length()) {
            digitSum += c.top();
            c.pop();
        }
        if (o < b.length()) {
            digitSum += d.top();
            d.pop();
        }

        if (digitSum >= 10) {
            carry = 1;
            digitSum -= 10;
        } else {
            carry = 0;
        }

        result.push_back(digitSum);  // Store the result in reverse order.
    }

    if (carry > 0) {
        result.push_back(carry);
    }

    // Print the result in reverse order.
    for (int i = result.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        cout << result[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Next project wil be minus calculating :)

Comment: I would also recommend using a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). In particular, the best beginner c++ book is *"C++ Primer by Lippman 5th edition"*. If you search that term on the web you'll find pdfs for it.